# Play Store Android apps are not updating in Android Lollipop (Error code: 495)

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop

I have installed the latest factory image for Android Lollipop version from Google site to my Nexus 5 device.

When I am updating apps from Play Store, "Update all" option is not working. Some of individual apps like Maps, Calendar also shows indefinite spinner. Google Fit, Google Keep, Maps and Play Music apps are not updating. Getting error:

> Could not be downloaded due to an error (495)

Comment: Did you turned off the auto-update function in the Play Store?

Comment: NO. it is enabled. I have tried with disabling it but same issue

Comment: Also, try clearing the cache and the data stored by the Google PlayStore app by heading over to the application manager and see if that works for you ?

Comment: Done. Still same issue. I an see playstore app is udated shall I remove all the updates?

Comment: Well, I don't think that it will make any difference anyway can try doing that too !

Comment: Google fit google keep, Maps and play music apps are not updating. Getting error: could not be downloaded due to an error (495)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following...

**<<1>>**

1. Go to Settings > Apps > slide to "All" apps.
2. From the list of apps find Google Play Store > Clear Data and Clear Cache.
3. From the list of apps find Google Services Framework > Clear Cache.
4. Now, try to install or update app from Google Play Store.
5. If it still didn’t work try uninstalling Google Play Store updates.

If the above steps couldn't solve your issue,

**<<2>>**

1. Go to Settings > Accounts > Google > Remove your Gmail account.
2. Again go to Settings > Apps > slide to "All" apps.
3. Force Stop, Clear Data and Cache for Google Play Store,Google Services Framework and Download Manager.
4. Now again go to settings > Accounts > Google > Add your Gmail account.
5. Restart your android and re-run Google Play Store and update/install your apps.